# Regular Expression for word array between brackets

Tags: regex

I need to extract words from this:

```
[[hello] hello [world] world]
```

Result:

```
[hello]
[world]
```

I tried:

```
\[(\[\w*\])+\]
```

But this expression for only one word, i need few words

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried \[(\[\w*\])+\] but this expression for only one word between brackets

Comment: That would appear to work for your example. Do you not only want one word? Give a [mre] to explain the actual problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i dont know how create expression for few words

Comment: Why not `\[[^[\]]+?\]`? Or are you not specifying the `g` modifier, which would give you *all* matches?

Comment: @trincot no, need expression to extract words inside brackets only in other brackets

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that referenced Q&A does not deal with the additional requirement of the outer brackets.

Comment: @trincot Ok, I doubled checked, but note you do not need lazy quantifiers in your solution.

Comment: Indeed, they are a remnant of an earlier version. Will update. Thanks.

Comment: I assume that may be part of a string (e.g., `"Say [hello] or [[hello] hello [world] world] or both"`). Correct?

Comment: when yuio say `need expression to extract words inside brackets only in other brackets` yuio immediatly referr to _balanced text_. why use a regex at all, or even try unless using the right engine that does this, you don't say, yes ? but look yuio got 2 attempts, both fail, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to match content in square brackets, which itself occurs within a bracket pair.

I would suggest using look-ahead, skipping any other stand-alone bracket pair, and looking for an additional closing bracket. If that is found, then the match counts:

[`\[[^[\]]+\](?=[^[\]]*(\[[^[\]]+\])*[^[\]]*\])`](https://regex101.com/r/bEjL5v/1)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you!

Comment: not a balanced text regexr, if it only care about the right side how can it match between brackets, i mean right, yes ? why submit as an aqnsw4er ? matches '`[asfd]` ]' and wont match '[asfd] []]' even though it shuldnt anerway.

Comment: Indeed, this answer assumes that the input has balanced brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If 2 steps are ok for you, try this (corrected version):

```
String s = "[[hello1] hello [world1] world]";
String t = s.replaceAll("^\\[(.+)\\]$","$1");
String result = t.replaceAll("([^\\[\\]]+)(\\[|$)","\n$2");
System.out.println(t);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches of the following regular expression will extract the strings of interest.

```
(?:^.*?\[|\G)[ \w+]*\K\[[ \w+]*\](?=[ \w+]*(?:\[[ \w+]*\][ \w+]*)*\])
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/H0jbm2/2/)

This should work with every regex engine that supports `\G` and `\K` (defined  below), which includes PCRE (PHP), Perl, Ruby, Python's regex module, among others.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?:          : begin non-capture group
  ^          : match beginning of string
  .*?\[      : match 0+ characters, lazily, then '['
  |          : or
  \G         : assert position at the end of the previous match or the
               start of the string for the first match
)            : end non-capture group
[ \w+]*      : match 0+ characters in character class
\K           : forget everything matched so far and 
\[           : match '['
[ \w+]*      : match 0+ characters in character class
\]           : match ']'
(?=          : begin positive lookahead
  [ \w+]*    : match 0+ characters in character class
  (?:        : begin non-capture group
    \[       : match '['
    [ \w+]*  : match 0+ characters in character class
    \]       : match ']'
    [ \w+]*  : match 0+ characters in character class
  )          : end non-capture group
  *          : execute non-capture group 0+ times
  \]         : match ']'
)            : end positive lookahead
```

This asserts the parentheses are balanced between the enclosing brackets (but not everywhere in the string).